# Why don't Dirichlet series with higher order zeros at $s=1$ have faster converging partial sums at $s=1$?

Tags: nt.number-theory

When examining the Dirichlet series generated by $\mu(n)\gcd(n,k)$ for some fixed value $k$, I found something counterintuitive. To set this up, we can expand as an Euler product to see that

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)\gcd(n,k)}{n^s}&=\prod_{p}\left(1-\frac{\gcd(p,k)}{p^s}\right)\\
&=\prod_{p|k}\left(1-\frac{\gcd(p,k)}{p^s}\right)\cdot\prod_{p\nmid k}\left(1-\frac{\gcd(p,k)}{p^s}\right)\\
&=\prod_{p|k}\left(1-\frac{p}{p^s}\right)\cdot\prod_{p\nmid k}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)\\
&=\prod_{p|k}\left(\frac{1-\frac{p}{p^s}}{1-\frac{1}{p^s}}\right)\cdot\prod_{p}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)\\
\end{align*}
We can now define $g(s)=\prod_{p|k}\frac{1-p^{1-s}}{1-p^{-s}}$ we get that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)\gcd(n,k)}{n^s}=\frac{g(s)}{\zeta(s)}$$

The thing I find strange is that, about $s=1$, $1-p^{s}$ is bounded but $1-p^{1-s}\sim \log(p)(s-1)$ and so if we let $\omega(k)$ be the number of distinct prime factors of $k$ we have that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)\gcd(n,k)}{n^s}\sim C_0 (s-1)^{\omega(k)+1}$$

where

$$C_0=\prod_{p|k}\frac{\log(p)}{1-p^{-1}}$$

> Since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)\gcd(n,k)}{n^s}$ has a higher order zero at $s=1$ and vanishes very quickly, it would be my intuition that around $s=1$ the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)\gcd(n,k)}{n}$ would converge to $0$ very fast, but numerical evidence would suggest that it converges much slower than $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}$. What is the intuition behind why the speed of Dirchlet series vanishing at $s=1$ and convergence $s=1$ not being related?

As an aside, it is obvious by Newman's Tauberian theorem that this sum does indeed converge at $s=1$, it is just the speed that bothers me.

Comment: The order of the zero of $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n) (n,k)}{n^s}$ at $s = 1$ determines the rate at which this Dirichlet series tends to zero as $s \searrow 1$. However, this says nothing about the size of the partial sums $\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\mu(n) (n,k)}{n}$ as $x \to \infty$ other than this is $o(1)$ (by a Tauberian theorem or Perron's formula). Instead, the decay rate of $\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\mu(n) (n,k)}{n}$ is dictated by the zero free region of the analytic continuation of the Dirichlet series left of the line $\Re(s) = 1$.